# how update buttons (rooms) on specific date acording to database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

[image]

I create database using *curentdate* (1-25) as `parent id` and using *room* (08-00_11-00_karpet1-) as `child id`. inside this database are user information that order that room (`child id`) on that date (`parent id`).

**Question 1**

using this layout design, how do i **disable button** that have been ordered so that indicate that room no longer available.

(example. user order **karpet 14-17** on **1-28**, when user create order database will update database `datajadwal` based on *date* (**parentid**) >> *room* (**childid**) >> userinformation (email.name.phone.etc) )

**Question 2**

each date have 5 rooms. when specific date click, room button will disabled according to the data on `datajadwal` and on that date (`parentid`), if there are no room data (`childid`) that means that room are available.

**my situation** =
 i don't know hot to get the `childid`

```
private void datajadwalupdate(){
        databseJadwal = database.getReference("datajadwal").child(haritanggalOrder);
        databseJadwal.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dateSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    final String rooms = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    databseJadwal.child(haritanggalOrder).child(rooms).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

this is where I'm, but got error on a null object reference

Comment: Kotlin or Java?

Comment: Java sir.........

Comment: You dont need the nested listener as I said on my anwer you need to use a model to represent your object, read this https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you will need all data under `datajadwal` to disable the correct buttons. In that case you can use a listener like this:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("datajadwal");
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dateSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String date = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            for (DataSnapshot bookingSnapshot: dateSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String booking = bookingSnapshot.getKey();

                // TODO: parse the booking into the time slot and room name
                String timeslot = ...
                String room = ...

                // TODO: find the button for the room name and time slot and disable it

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate throught the childs of the snapshot and check the data, if there is user data then disable it.

```
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child(id).child(date);
ref.addValueEventListener(...

    onDataChange...{
          for (Snapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                 //set the names as you are doing it
                 boolean occupied = child.hasChild("email)
                 button.setEnabled(!occupied)
           }

    }
```

You should create a POJO representing your entity and get the value from the snapshot child with `getValue(YourPOJO.class)`

Comment: yeah sir, right i don't know how to get the `childid`. pojo ? how to do that sir ?